# Using random operators

Tags: java, android, math

I'm making an android maths game which gives users the some questions to answer with random numbers, and just to make it perfect I want to try and use random operators i.e. add/sub/multi/divide

So far I have the semi-random equation method:

```
public void easyGame(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    final int a = (int) rand.nextInt(50)+1;
    final int b = (int) rand.nextInt(50)+1;
    final int c = (int) rand.nextInt(10)+1;
    String aString = Integer.toString(a);
    String bString = Integer.toString(b);
    String cString = Integer.toString(c);
    String display = aString + " + " + bString + " - " + cString + " =";
    questionLabel.setText(display);
    c1 = a + b - c;
}
```

This gives me random numbers, stored in c1 which is a static int, and compared with user input later on in the code.

I've seen how random operators are made using arrays and stuff, but I don't know/understand how to use them in the `c1 = a + b - c;` statement, i.e. how do you replace it with the + and - operations.

Please let me know if you know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use random numbers to do anything you want with them. For example this (very incomplete) example should give you an idea how you can randomize the operators too.

```
int operator1 =  (int) rand.nextInt(4);
// ...
char op;
switch(operator1) {
   case 0: op = '+'; break;
   case 1: op = '-'; break;
   // ...
}
String display = aString + op + ...
c1 = a;
switch(operator1) {
   case 0: c1 += b; break;
   case 1: c1 -= b; break;
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes some sense to me. Just a quick question, the second switch will only work for 2 integer equations right? i.e. 1 + 1, 1 - 1 etc, and not 3 + 1 - 1

Comment: If you want 3 random operators it gets complicated since you have to make sure that you don't calculate (a+b)*c. That would require more complex logic but its possible :)